# iOS 12.4 AVAudioRecorder crash CrashIfClientProvidedBogusAudioBufferList

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder

I'm trying to understand why `AVAudioRecorder.record()` crashing on iOS 12.4 simulator (I don't have 12.4 device now to check)

Can't find almost any info about this specific crash

Here is my `AVAudioRecorder` setup:

```
func startRecording() {
    let dirPath =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let recordName = "record.wav"
    audioURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath + "/" + recordName)

    do {
        let recorder  = try AVAudioRecorder(url: self.audioURL, settings: [:])
        try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: .defaultToSpeaker)
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
        audioRecorder = recorder
        audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
        audioRecorder.delegate = self
        audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
        audioRecorder.record()
    } catch {
        self.finishRecording(success: false)
        print(error)
    }
}
```

I also check permissions before record:

```
audioSession.requestRecordPermission { granted in
            if granted {
                self.recordTapped()
            } else {
                print("not granted")
            }
        }
```

All the info I get from error stack trace:

[image]